# Ruby on Rails: validation two inclusion conditions with range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have validation on a model to validate "year built".

```
  validates :year_built, inclusion: { in: 1900..(Date.today.year) }
```

This column was recently changed to a string to allow for two more options "To Be Built" and "New".

I would like to validate that the only accepted data will be what is above (1900..date) as well as these two strings:

```
validates :year_built, inclusion: { in: 1900..(Date.today.year) || ['New', 'To Be Built']}
```

Is there a way I can check for both?

Comment: `in: ('1900'..Date.today.year.to_s).to_a.concat(['New', 'To Be Built'])`

Comment: `in: (1900..(Date.today.year)).to_a.concat(['New', 'To Be Built'])`

Comment: thank you. if you want to write it as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: Note that you have a subtle bug. `Date.today.year` will be evaluated when the class is loaded. If the class is loaded on, say, Dec 31 and then the validation is applied in January it can fail unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for [validations in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

The inclusion validator is a basic validator for ranges OR arrays, but doesn't allow for this type of "conditional" logic.

While I doubt that changing a year column to string was the best choice in the first place ([you can also conditionally validate based on another column](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless)), you could adapt your idea and `map`/`collect` the years you want to match against and add the other options to that array, e.g.:

```
validates :year_built, inclusion: { in: (1900..(Date.today.year)).collect(&:to_s) + ['New', 'To Be Built']}
```

But I think this options puts too much in a single hard to parse line. If you want to keep your column a String-column you should consider writing a custom validator function, see [here for how to write one](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods).

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I could have kept it as integer as put those two options as 0 and 1? No arithmetic will be done on the column, so I don't think it's a big deal.

Comment: It probably is not a big deal now, but I generally prefer to keep types predictable (maybe one day you'll have a view that presents buildings per decade). I'd rather introduce another column to indicate e.g. state, which would contain e.g. one of "to_be_built", "new" and "built" (another column to validate ;) ) and then a conditional validation like `validates :year_built, inclusion: { in: 1900..(Date.today.year) }, if:  :built?` depending on a method `#built?`